# VB 6 Checking if a file on the network exists takes too long

Tags: file, vb6, network-programming, directory

The following code:

```
    If FileExists(XCustPath + "XCust.dat") Then
        XCustRun
    End If
```

and this code:

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal Fname As String) As Boolean

Dim lRetVal As Long
Dim OfSt As OFSTRUCT

lRetVal = OpenFile(Fname, OfSt, OF_EXIST)
If lRetVal <> HFILE_ERROR Then
    FileExists = True
Else
    FileExists = False
End If

End Function
```

XCustPath points to a mapped network location with the file XCust.dat inside it.

But on the line:

```
lRetVal = OpenFile(Fname, OfSt, OF_EXIST)
```

It takes forever and locks up my program for 20-30 seconds. It needs to check if this file exists on the network in less than 1 second as it is for a legacy point of sale application. Is there anyway I can force it to timeout the line of code if it takes longer than a second? If it does exist it runs smoothly and perfect. Or a VERY quick way of checking if a file on the network exists?

Comment: Is the file on a server that is down? Also, you need to close the file if it does exist.

Answer (score 5):

This should be faster:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fso.fileexists(Fname) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This ....

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal Fname As String) As Boolean
        FileExists = iif (Dir(Fname)<>"", true, false)
End Function
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple although no need for the iif as `Dir(Fname)<>""` is a boolean expression, and beware that an non-existing unc will generate a runtime error (unlike a non-existing drive letter)

Comment: This resets current `Dir` enumeration and can't be used while looping folders with `sNext = Dir(sMask): Do While LenB(sNext) <> 0 ... sNext = Dir : Loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest will be to check the file attributes (for legacy reasons). I'm using `API` function like this

```
Private Declare Function GetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Public Function FileExists(sFile As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = (GetFileAttributes(sFile) <> -1) ' INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
End Function
```

You can rewrite it with VB's `GetAttr` and an error handler like this

```
Public Function FileExists(sFile As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo QH
    GetAttr sFile
    FileExists = True
QH:
End Function
```

I prefer the first version as I keep `Break on All Errors` setting on for all my projects.