# How to test if network folder is up on VB6

Tags: vb6

I have an application on VB6 that on a specific action it brings to user a form filled with some images. These images are located on an external server. Sometimes this server is down due to some maintenence and it cause some issues on my application (like Bad file error 52).

I wanna know if there is any way to "test" the folder access with less timeout like 2seconds. If server do not responde after 2 seconds I'm gonna unload the picture forms so the users can continues working normally.

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: How are you getting the images ?

Comment: I'm getting pictures using Function LoadPicture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim exists as Boolean

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
exists = fso.FolderExists("\\MyServer\SomeFolder\")

If Not exists Then
    'Let the user know the server is down
Else
    'Server is up so load your pictures
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is any way to avoid the time out bcs it keep more than 30s when the server do not respond on exists variable. It's possible to change this value of timeout?

Comment: I'm not sure without being able to reproduce the kind of delay you're getting. There's another post with some other suggestions you can try to see if the check is faster.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848923/vb-6-checking-if-a-file-on-the-network-exists-takes-too-long

Comment: Another suggestion would be to ping the server's IP address

This link has a module  you can add to your code with a ping method
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300197

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I think I'm gonna try the second option.